# How to shorthand all these if checks and reassigns?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that I want to set to something based on whether other variables are defined or not + 1 boolean flag. I was wondering how can it be shortened:

```
let name = banana;

let test = name.toLowerCase();

if (vegetable?.name && isTasty) {
    test = cucumber;
}

if (vegetable?.name && !isTasty) {
    test = cauliflower;
}

if (fruit?.name) {
    test = strawberry
}
```

Comment: `params?.articleId ?? controller?.activityConfig?.slug ?? (isFromActivity || name.toLowerCase())`

Comment: you're right, I edited it

Comment: @kikon that could make `test` the literal `true`

Comment: @kikon that still doesn't fix the issue, because if `isFromActivity` is `true` then it short circuits, ignoring `name.toLowerCase()`, and evaluating to the literal `true`

Comment: Yeah I finally got it - @GerardoFurtado 's answer is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one-liner with arguably limited readability, you can put a ternary in the mix:

```
let test = params?.articleId ?? (isFromActivity ? 
    controller?.activityConfig?.slug ?? name.toLowerCase() : name.toLowerCase())
```